# Azure Devops Release Pipeline batching doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, azure-devops, maui

I don't seem to be able to get my builds to batch in Azure Devops. I have a YAML pipeline. I have set this:

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - DEV
  paths:
    include:
      - NetCore
```

and also I have gone in to the visual Triggers screen and ticked "Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here" and  "Batch changes while a build is in progress", but the builds still seem to queue up.

So if I checkin 3 times while a build is running, I end up with 3 builds additional builds rather than just 1.

Just to explain further - if I make 3 checkins and put a comment against each one:
Checkin 1
Checkin 2
Checkin 3

What happens is when I do checkin 1 a build kicks off. I then do checkin 2 and 3 - nothing happens. So I have no way of seeing that there is another build queued up. When checkin 1 build completes I then get another build running for Checkin 2.

Anyone else seen the same thing?

Answer (score -1):

There is the detailed explanation how it works [Batching CI runs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#batching-ci-runs)

> To clarify this example, let us say that a push A to master caused the above pipeline to run. While that pipeline is running, additional pushes B and C occur into the repository. These updates do not start new independent runs immediately. But after the first run is completed, all pushes until that point of time are batched together and a new run is started.

The git sample for yaml:

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - master
```

The result of 3 commits:

[image]

Comment: I have updated the question with more yaml